# Interface for users that need to fill in data for thousands of items

Tags: interface, data, categorization

The problem I encounter is that I have thousands of items a day (e.g. transactions of toys that have been purchased in a store). My goal is to provide the users with an interface to fill in manually 10+ data fields on this transaction (e.g. toy category, is it the main toy or something you purchase as extra, what age is it for, etc.).
Then, I would categorize the data by the information the users provided me.
How would you recommend doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the data would still eventually be categorized, the best way to render the interface to the user is to group whatever field you want them to fill into classes so that the manual filling can be less tasking.

Let's say a user once to input the purchase of a wristwatch for a toddler. This could fall under 'accessories' class, the 'age range' of say below 12, then a 'primary' or 'secondary' item class.

This way the user can easily predict that this item should fall under these categories and you have organized data with a good interface.

Another plus would be having a template of all the items in the store and having a default group beforehand. That way all the user would do is check each class of data you want to gather information for and just adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! How would you recommend designing the manual filling? a simple grid, a form etc.? assuming that I'm going to gather data from multiple toy stores, every day? I want to make the interface as simple as possible.

Comment: If the user is going to enter data multiple times then I would recommend a form with several checkboxes and/or dropdowns. The user should be able to select things like their toy store and as many other information that can be generic. This should strike a balance between having to type multiple times and having to select from a list of options.